# What does "2×Basic" mean in ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper, intellisense, resharper-8.0

I have Visual Studio 2012 and ReSharper 8.2. I noticed that if you bring up intellisense with the usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> again, some other options pop up. Some of them will be other matching symbols from libraries which are not included in the current project, but at the bottom there's this strange little "2×Basic" item, which doesn't appear to do anything.

[image: 2×Basic]

You can't click on it, and there's no tool tip. Does anybody know what this is for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the "double basic (code) completion", a feature that was introduced in ReSharper 8. You can read more about it in [this blog post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/07/02/code-completion-improvements-in-resharper-8/). Basically (hah, no pun intended!), double (and sometimes triple) completion invocation will bring more available options to code completion. The "basic", in this case, refers to the type of completion. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is the basic completion shortcut, there are also Smart Completion and Import Completion types available in ReSharper.

Comment: Ahh thanks. That makes sense. I looked in the documentation, but just from seeing that "2×Basic" I didn't know what it was. It would've been helpful if there was at least a tool tip or something like that. That blog post is very informative, too.